# Spring Data Rest and Hateoas

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I was following a simple tutorial to test the behavior of spring data rest, with annotating a repository with @RestResource annotation. 
I have very simple scenario:
Jpa User Entity and UserRepository annotated with @RestResource

```
@RestResource(path="users", rel="users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

List<User> findUserByUserName(@Param("userName")String userName);
}
```

I use annotation config initialization and I try to register RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration, so the UserRepository can be registered.
But my application is not starting and I have the following exception

```
INFO  Registering annotated classes: [class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration,class com.ncau.WebMvcConfiguration]
ERROR Context initialization failed 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport$HypermediaType; cannot be cast to org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport$HypermediaType
at org.springframework.hateoas.config.HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(HypermediaSupportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:90) ~[spring-hateoas-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I use 
spring-hateoas: 0.8.0.RELEASE
spring-data-rest-webmv: 2.0.0.RC1
spring-framework: 4.0.0.RELEASE
spring-data-jpa:1.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SDR 2.0.0.RC1, use

```
spring-hateoas 0.9.0.RELEASE
spring-data-jpa 1.5.0.RC1
```

SDR will export all repositories by default, you don't need to annotate them.